# Put value of for loop in next function

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I new to python and stuck in for loop function can someone help on on how can I get value of "i" in next function.

formula

```py
from pixelate import pixelate

for i in range(197):
    pixelate('/Users/amanrai/Desktop/lady/%i.png', '/Users/amanrai/Desktop/lady/rotate/%i.png', 20)
```

I want the "i" value in after the directory name

would appreciate if some expert can help me.

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping me out.
Found solution for my issue.

Comment: If you find the solution here don't forget change the ask as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use format:

```
for i in range(197):
    pixelate('/Users/amanrai/Desktop/lady/{}.png'.format(i), '/Users/amanrai/Desktop/lady/rotate/{}.png'.format(i), 20)
```

See this wonderful [**cheat sheet**](https://pyformat.info/) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```py
for i in range(197):
    img = f'/Users/amanrai/Desktop/lady/{i}.png'
    img_rotate = f'/Users/amanrai/Desktop/lady/{i}.png'
    pixelate(img, img_rotate, 20)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an f-string:

```py
pixelate(f'/Users/amanrai/Desktop/lady/{i}.png', f'/Users/amanrai/Desktop/lady/rotate/{i}.png', 20)
```

String interpolation or f-string for short allow you to put variables inside a string. This feature was added in Python 3.6. If you are a previous version you must use `str.format` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
for i in range(197):
    pixelate(f"/Users/amanrai/Desktop/lady/{i}.png', '/Users/amanrai/Desktop/lady/rotate/{i}.png', 20")
```